# Access the blog from the main menu

Tags: routes, nodes

I want to add a link in the main menu to Blog a whole, ie the blog you go all blog entries of all users. I use the blog module and yes I can insert the access to different users blogs, but not the general blog. I do not know what is the link to the blog generic.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create a menu pointing to http://yoursite.com/blog. The page showing all the blogs posts uses blog as path. (See [blog_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!blog!blog.module/function/blog_menu/7).)

```
  $items['blog'] = array(
    'title' => 'Blogs',
    'page callback' => 'blog_page_last',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
    'file' => 'blog.pages.inc',
  );
```

Comment: Actually this menu item is already defined by Blog module. So the only thing the OP should do, is editing this menu item under `admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation` and select as parent link the <Main Menu>